# Snake word puzzles

Tags: word-search

Find the nine letter word that "snakes" through the grid. Every letter is only used once. If you are stuck on one then write it down and it will easier (in my opinion). And please **do not** search it up.

```
 R A L
 S M A
 U P I
```

Try another one:

```
 L E L
 A S E
 I T C
```

And the last one:

```
 N E L
 O T G
 S I N
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are made easier by the fact that each word must both start and end in a corner or at the centre: there can be no path visiting all the letters that starts or ends on an "edge" letter.  (To see this without trying any paths, colour the letter squares in a checkerboard pattern. Since any "snake path" can only have alternating colours, a full path must start and end on the colour that appears on more squares.)

The first word is

> marsupial

The second is

> celestial

and the third one is

> singleton (notice how the tempting "maybe it ends in -ing" idea is ruled out by the geometry constraint given above)

The last two words were discovered by [Shahriar Mahmud Sajid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/69039/36023) before me.

Comment: i also thought about your solution to the first word, but didn't know it was an actual word,hence didn't answer :D you, sir, have a strong vocabulary.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid I also have [a very good dictionary](https://onelook.com/?w=marsupial&ls=a) :-)

Comment: Just to make sure did you search them up?

Comment: @Duck, I'm not quite certain what you mean. I didn't use any help whatsoever, and solved them 100% manually, if that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 7):

partial answer:

second one is-

> celestial

third one -

> singleton